# not able to build android project in mac OS

Tags: android, cordova

I am newbie in phonegap. I have created the project for all platform in mac OS.I am able to build other than android platform. I am using cordova 5.1.1 version.

**`cordova build android`**

```
cordova build android

Running command: /Users/abc/AndroidDevelopments/Project/abcDemo/abcDemo1.1/platforms/android/cordova/build
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/abc/Library/Android/sdk/
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
Running: /Users/abc/AndroidDevelopments/Project/abcDemo/abcDemo1.1/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/abc/AndroidDevelopments/Project/abcDemo/abcDemo1.1/platforms/android/build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
> Configuring > 0/2 projects > root project > Resolving dependencies ':classpath'


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+.
Required by:
:android:unspecified
> Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.
> Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
> Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
> Malformed reply from SOCKS server

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5 mins 6.688 secs

/Users/abc/AndroidDevelopments/Project/abcDemo/abcDemo1.1/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
throw e;
^
Error code 1 for command: /Users/abc/AndroidDevelopments/Project/abcDemo/abcDemo1.1/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/abc/AndroidDevelopments/Project/abcDemo/abcDemo1.1/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/abc/AndroidDevelopments/Project/abcDemo/abcDemo1.1/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
        Error: /Users/abc/AndroidDevelopments/Project/abcDemo/abcDemo1.1/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
        at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)
        at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
        at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
```

Comment: Have you added `ANDROID_HOME/tools` and `ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools` to `PATH` ?

Comment: try updating npm and node to the latest versions

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use maven local repo instead of remote one you need to add jar files to local repository.

Local maven repository is located at

> ~/.m2/repository

You can download it from this link,
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/builder/

To install this library type in your command line:

> mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.android.tools.build \
>   -DartifactId=builder \
>   -Dversion=0.5.4 \
>   -Dfile=builder-0.5.4.jar \
>   -Dpackaging=jar \
>   -DgeneratePom=true

Then in build.gradle file change,

> mavenCentral()

to

> mavenLocal()

This might help :)

Answer (score 0):

Configuring Android SDK path for me was a headake.

Try this:

1. Download & Install Android Studio
2. Install the API you need
3. Open Android Studio and go to Configure -> Project Default -> Project Structure

There you will find the paths for the SDK. From here you can follow this link http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

Basically what you will do is to add to your .bash_profile the path to the SDK and Android Tools. COPY AND PASTE the path form step 3 into the bash file.

So...

4. Open Terminal and execute this command `source ~/.bash_profile` this will create the .bash file in your user root directory
5. Open the .bash_profile (It will be hidden, so perhaps you'll need to execute this to make hidden files visible. In terminal execute `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES`)
6. Edit the bash_profile using the text edit tool as shown on the link above

Good luck!